# XML select sing node and loop through it

Tags: c#, xml

I'm having some issues looping through an XML node.

To begin, here is the general format of the XML file:

```
<Config>
  <Facilities>
    <Facility>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <Name>Facility Name</Name>
      <Profiles>
        <Profile>
            <Name>Value</Name>
            <Item2>Value</2>
        </Profile>
        <Profile>
            <Name>Another Value</Name>
        </Profile>
      </Profiles>
    </Facility>
    <Facility>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <Name>Facility Name</Name>
      <Profiles>
        <Profile>
            <Name>Value</Name>
        </Profile>
      </Profiles>
    </Facility>
  </Facilities>
</Config>
```

And here's the code I'm using:

```
XmlDocument configFile = new XmlDocument();
configFile.Load(CONFIG_FILE);

XmlNodeList nodeList = configFile.SelectNodes("/Config/Facilities/Facility[ID[text()='" + facilityID + "']]/Profiles/Profile");
foreach (XmlNode no in nodeList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(no["Name"].InnerText);
    //myList.Items.Add(no["Name"].InnerText);
}
```

Basically, I want to loop through the facilities and select the facility with a specific ID (this id is derived from the `facilityID` that I set earlier in my code...and yes I've checked, it's being set correctly). I then want to go through the profiles associated with the facility and loop through them. I want to be able to take all the elements in each `<Profile>` as applicable.

However, when I execute this code, it's not returning anything in the debug console.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/169598/Parse-XML-Documents-by-XMLDocument-and-XDocument

Comment: As @Calliah pointed out in that answer, there is what I assumed to be a typo in your example, where you list `<Item2>Value</2>`. If that's not a typo and your XML might have errors like that, that vastly changes the approach we'll have to take.

Comment: Heh...live and learn I guess. The typo was the culprit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exists in your file, but there appears to be XML errors in the example posted.

```
<Item2>Value</2>
```

If I remove that, I'm able to correctly see the value expected. For example, if I use a value of "1" for facilityID, I receive

```
Value
Another Value
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like this? This is using the [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx) class, of course. I tend to prefer it because it's easier to debug and, at least for me, easier to deploy.

```
var root = XElement.Load(CONFIG_FILE).Element("Facilities");

var facility = root.Elements("Facility").FirstOrDefault(c => c.Element("ID").Value == facilityID.ToString());

return facility.Element("Profiles").Elements("Profile");
```

It doesn't have any error handling, but you can add that in as necessary.

I don't know if you want to do this or not, it depends how you'll be using it, but you could also replace the last line there with this:

```
return facility.Element("Profiles").Elements("Profile").Select(c => c.Element("Name").Value);
```

And that would give you just the names. Again, depends on what exactly you're looking for. I just added this since I see your example is only printing out the names.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions; however, it was a measly typo that was causing the issue.